# Event when "select-all" button clicked in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently implementing a data table using Vuetify, but I have stumbled into a problem while trying to react to a click on the "select-all" button in a data table. Right now, when the select-all button is clicked, the currently visible rows are selected (which is exactly what I want). However, I would like to be notified of the user clicking on this select-all button.

My plan is to provide the user with a "select everything" button, once the user clicks this "select-all" checkbox, but I can't seem to find a way (without having to reside to hacks) to get notified of a click on the "select-all" button.

Comment: There is no built-in event for this (at least in v1.5.16) so you have to either implement the checkbox yourself and not rely on the `select-all` attribute or try to watch the `v-model` of the data-table and detect whether the length of this array is equal to the total number of items in the data-table.

Answer (score 4):

There is a toggle-select-all method.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :value="selected"
      @toggle-select-all="selectAll"
      :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      show-select
      class="elevation-1"
    >
    </v-data-table>
    <v-dialog>
      <v-card>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Javascript is below:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    selectAll(event) {
      if (event.status) {
        alert('selected all')
      } else {
        alert('deselected all')
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [],
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      headers: ['headers', 'data'],
      desserts: ['your', 'data']
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This works great.  Thanks!  I'm new to Vue and our coding standards enforce that we don't use the "@" ie: `@toggle-select-all="selectAll"` I tried many things like v:on:click/change etc. but I couldn't get any longhand notation to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to get around that. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes, `v-on:toggle-select-all` works great.  I had tried it before posting my question, but had put an extra ':' in it (v:on:toggle-select-all), so it didn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: Please use event.value instead of event.ststus

Comment: For those who arrive now like me... In the data table there is the [select-strategy](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/selection/#select-strategies) attribute, which when defined as "all", when selecting the checkbox it selects all the rows in the entire table, different from the default "page" which selects all of the current page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `:value` and `@input` on the Vuetify table rather than v-model. Check if the selected array is equal to items per page when the user selects something.

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :value="selected"
      @input="enterSelect($event)"
      :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      show-select
      class="elevation-1"
    >
    </v-data-table>
    <v-dialog>
      <v-card>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Javascript is below:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    enterSelect(values) {
      if (values.length == this.itemsPerPage) {
        alert('selected all')
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [],
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      headers: ['headers', 'data'],
      desserts: ['your', 'data']
    }
  }
})
```

Working example here: https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/QWLyaog?editors=1010